# Spring Boot: Application is displaying 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run Spring Boot REST API application, but I am getting a 404 error.

```
package com.spring.boot.entry;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HelloController.class)
public class CourseApiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }
}

package com.spring.boot.entry.hello;
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hi First Spring boot application ";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.spring.boot.quickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Spring Boot API</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I also tried `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HelloController.class)`,
but no luck. Could you please help to resolve this issue?

If I hit http://localhost:8080/hello url then I am getting 404.

Comment: please show the startup log

Comment: remove this @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HelloController.class)

Comment: @sajib, it works with that.

Comment: Error here: @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HelloController.class)

you should define BASE package, instead of class. Change on package where HelloController.class is.

Comment: @Reborn - this is incorrect, the `basePackageClasses` property expects a `Class`, see the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackageClasses--). The `basePackage` property takes a String of the package name, which might be what you're thinking of.

Comment: Even I tried for adding basePackage=("com.spring.boot.entry.hello"). But no luck

Answer (score 4):

I executed your code on my system and unless you've messed up with the directory structure it is working as expected. Cross check that once.

[image]

CourseApiApp.java

[image]

HelloController.java

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: I have verified directory structure as well. However as I mentioned above, its the same issue. Not able to identify where the problem is

Comment: No error. Just 404 error in browser.       Below is console log.2018-08-11 2018-08-11 22:19:22.476  INFO 4236 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-11 22:19:22.488  INFO 4236 --- [           main] com.spring.boot.entry.CourseApiApp       : Started CourseApiApp in 8.765 seconds (JVM running for 10.559)

Comment: And localhost:8080 atleast should give apache home page as per my understanding. But I don't even see apache home page itself

Comment: Are you able to see the URL mappings in  your console. Something like : 
`2018-08-11 22:28:44.741  INFO 19272 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/hello]}" onto public java.lang.String com.spring.boot.entry.hello.HelloController.sayHello()`

Comment: I have changed the spring-boot-starter-parent version from 1.4.2.RELEASE to 1.5.9.RELEASE. Now I am able to see output. I don't know what is the problem with old version.